# how to subquery between two tables

Tags: sql, subquery

There are two tables, closure and code.

In `CLOSURE` table, there are four columns like below.

```
CLOSURE_SEQ     NUMBER             NOT NULL,
SUPERTYPE_SEQ   NUMBER             NOT NULL,
SUBTYPE_SEQ     NUMBER             NOT NULL,
VERSION_SEQ     NUMBER
```

In `CODE` table, there are two columns like below.

```
CODE_SEQ        NUMBER             NOT NULL,
CODE            VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)  NOT NULL
```

There are relationships between two tables, `SUPERTYPE_SEQ` and `SUBTYPE_SEQ` in `CLOSURE` have reference to `CODE_SEQ` in CODE table.

1, I would like to get `(SUPERTYPE_SEQ, SUBTYPE_SEQ)` from `CLOSURE` belonging to '1' `VERSION_SEQ` like following. 
`select SUPERTYPE_SEQ, SUBTYPE_SEQ from CLOSURE where VERSION_SEQ = 1;` It will return these rows.

```
SUPERTYPE_SEQ      SUBTYPE_SEQ
23984305             23984305
23984306             23984306
23984306             23984307
23984307             23984308
```

2, However, I do not have interest in `SUPERTYPE_SEQ`, `SUBTYPE_SEQ`, instead, I would like to see real `CODE` in `CODE` table by integrating the the CODE table together like following.

```
SUPERTYPE_CODE        SUBTYPE_CODE
C027750               C027750
C027751               C027751
C027751               C027752
C027752               C027753
```

To me, this is a little difficult to solve, could you please provide some solution for this? Actually, I am still confusing this problem is about subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 joins:

```
SELECT sup.CODE as SUPERTYPE_CODE, sub.CODE as SUBTYPE_CODE
FROM CLOSURE c
LEFT JOIN CODE sup on c.SUPERTYPE_SEQ = sup.CODE_SEQ
LEFT JOIN CODE sub on c.SUBTYPE_SEQ = sub.CODE_SEQ
```